# Make: Fatal error in reader: ... Unexpected end of line seen

Tags: makefile, c++, компиляция, linux

Создал Makefile, поместил его в папку с программой hadoopc++.cpp

```
CC = g++  
HADOOP_INSTALL = /export/hadoop-1.0.1/  
PLATFORM = Linux-i386-32  
CPPFLAGS = -m32 -I$(HADOOP_INSTALL)/c++/$(PLATFORM)/include

parindex: hadoopc++.cpp  
    $(CC) $(CPPFLAGS) $< -Wall -L$(HADOOP_INSTALL)/c++/$(PLATFORM)/lib -lhadooppipes \
    -lhadooputils -lpthread -g -O2 -o $@
```

согласно [Running C++ Programs on Hadoop](http://cs.smith.edu/dftwiki/index.php/Hadoop_Tutorial_2.2_--_Running_C%2B%2B_Programs_on_Hadoop). Затем перешел в папку с кодом с помощью cd и выполнил make parindex, на что мне выдало следующую ошибку

> `make: Fatal error in reader: Makefile, line 6: Unexpected end of line seen`

Comment: Попробуйте заменить пробелы на табы.

    parindex: hadoopc++.cpp  
    <tab>$(CC) $(CPPFLAGS) $< -Wall -...
    <tab>-lhadooputils -lpthread -g -...

Comment: @Котик_хочет_кушать, не помогло.

Answer (score 2):

У Вас после '\' наверняка пробел(ы) или табуляция. Поэтому и сообщение

> `make: Fatal error in reader: Makefile, line 6: Unexpected end of line seen`

В продолжении строки `<TAB>` не обязателен, хотя и не мешает.

Советую редактировать в emacs (в makefile-gmake-mode).